# BeautifulSoup Filter Function: multiple conditions

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am writing a python script that scrapes a web page and store information into lists.
The web page is not well-structured, so built-in filtering functions do not work for me.
Therefore I am trying to develop a custom filter function for find_all().

What I want to filter is something like this:

```
<td id="td343_23" style=display:>text</td>
```

where:

"td34_23" is varying for each , so regular expression is required.
tag "td" should be filtered, but tag "th" which has similar attributes should be excluded.
"style=display:" or "style" (without value) should be filtered, but "style=display:none" should be excluded.

What I have done is:

import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup4

```
def visibility(tag):
  displaynone = re.compile('(?!display:none)')
  idvalue = re.compile('td[0-9]+_[0-9]+')
  return bool(displaynone.search(tag.get('style'))) and tag.select('td') and bool(idvalue.search(tag.get('id')))

parsed = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
filtered = parsed.find_all(visibility)
```

Above code is not working at all.
Please tell me how to write filtering condition.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

---

### edited 2021/09/21

The page is kind of private, so I cannot provide the URL.
However, below is the sample of the HTML.

```
<html>
<div class="block">
<thread>
<tr>
<th id="td18_8" style>include</th>
<th id="td18_9" style="display:">include</th>
<th id="td18_10" style="display:none">exclude</th></tr>
</thread>
<thread>
<tr>
<th id="td19_8" style>include</th>
<th id="td19_9" style="display:">include</th>
<th id="td19_10" style="display:none">exclude</th>
</tr>
</thread>
</div>
</boxy>
<html>
```

Comment: Could you provide an url that is holding the information and an expected result, please Would be great.

Comment: @HedgeHog Thank you for the comment! I added the sample HTML data which is similar in structure as the original web page.

Answer (score 1):

`Regex` is not necessary for this, in principle it would also work with the `selector`:

```
soup.select('thread tr th:nth-of-type(1),th:nth-of-type(2)')
```

#### Working example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html='''<html>
<div class="block">
<thread>
<tr>
<th id="td18_8" style>include (td18_8)</th>
<th id="td18_9" style="display:">include (td18_9)</th>
<th id="td18_10" style="display:none">exclude</th>
</tr>
</thread>
<thread>
<tr>
<th id="td19_8" style>include (td19_8)</th>
<th id="td19_9" style="display:">include (td19_9)</th>
<th id="td19_10" style="display:none">exclude</th>
</tr>
</thread>
</div>
</boxy>
<html>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html")

[x.get_text() for x in soup.select('thread tr th:nth-of-type(1),th:nth-of-type(2)')]
```

#### Output:

```
['include (td18_8)',
 'include (td18_9)',
 'include (td19_8)',
 'include (td19_9)']
```